# Is it possible to write k code within q script?

Tags: kdb

I tried calling count function of k from q function but it is giving error.

```
{
  "k)"# 1 2 3 4 5 //~ count 1 2 3 4 5
 }[]
```

So, I have below questions:
1. Is it possible to write k code within q script?
2. If yes, then how can we write k code in q script? and does using k code within q script/function make the script/function more efficient and optimised?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible. I think what you are looking for is

```
{
 (#:) 1 2 3 4 5
}[]
```

This will perform a count on the list

2. In terms of speed, for functions like count the effect seems to be negligible.

```
q)\t:100000 {(#:) 1 2 3 4 5}[]
29
```

```
q)\t:100000 {count 1 2 3 4 5}[]
25
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: The increase in computation time is from parsing the function into `k` and would quickly become negligible as the computations become more intensive, Compare `count til 1000000000` vs  `(#:) til 1000000000` and the difference drops away

Comment: @CallumBiggs - In complete code base of a project which might have 1000's of lines of code and 10000's of functions like first, where, reverse, string etc. Won't using k code instead of q make a sizable difference?

Comment: If your are only ever processing very small pieces of data, sick isn't likely given that q is designed for Big Data

Comment: @Utsav If a project has 1000's of lines of q code then saving a few characters in k function calls is not going to drastically change the footprint. What would drastically change the footprint is more efficient coding, improved design and generalisation/re-usability of code. Moreover using k code embedded in q would make your project harder to read, debug, maintain and document. There's only a handful of situations where I think it would be justified using k code in a q project. At least that's my opinion

Comment: Thanks @terrylynch and CallumBiggs.

Comment: terrylynch and @CallumBiggs - Are there any resources which I can find online for good architectural design in kdb and to get good understanding of inner workings of kdb+ architecture like .u.upd and other imp functions.(I have read q for mortals and almost all white papers)

Answer (score 3):

A `k` function can be defined within a lambda by the method that Terry laid out, or in general, by invoking the definition via `value` like so

```
q)mins
&\
q)foo:{[x] value "k)minner:&\\";minner x}
q)foo 1 2 3
1 1 1
```

In fact you can easily create a neat little function to create `k` functions

```
q)makeK:{[x;y]value "k)",string[x],"::",string[y]}
q)makeK[`minfoo;&\]
q)minfoo
&\
q)minfoo 1 2 3
1 1 1
```

Eoins answer is a neater way to invoke the `k` functionality of primitives. In general, wrapping primitives with parenthesis will invoke the `k` functionality

```
q)dict:`a`b`c!(1 2 3;1 2 3;1 2 3)
q)flip dict
a b c
-----
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
q)(+:) dict
a b c
-----
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
q)(+:)~flip
1b
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Eoins and pamphlets approaches, it's also possible to execute strings as k code:

```
q){a:"k" "|1 2 3";a}[]
3 2 1
q)
q){b:("k" "#:")1 2 3;b}[]
3
```

However there is practically no advantage to writing code as k code - better to stick with q

Answer (score 1):

You can. One approach is to define the entire function in k:

```
q)k)f:{# 1 2 3}
q)f
k){# 1 2 3}
q)f[]
3
```

Comment: Incorrect. It is very possible to define a k function within a lambda. See Terrys or my answer.

Comment: Thanks @CallumBiggs. I've edited the answer to clarify that this just one approach.